# How to implement a drag and tap at same time

Tags: flutter, dart, uigesturerecognizer, flame

I'm making a flutter game with Flame and i have a problem implementing the controllers. The controllers are basically a joystick and a button atack. To the joystick i need the panStart, panUpdate and panEnd gestures, and to the attack button onTapUp and onTapDown. 
But i can't do both at same time, only a gesture at once

```
MultiTapGestureRecognizer tapper = MultiTapGestureRecognizer();
PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = PanGestureRecognizer();

panGesture.onEnd = game.onPanEnd;
panGesture.onUpdate = game.onPanUpdate;
panGesture.onStart = game.onPanStart;
panGesture.onCancel = game.onPanCancel;
tapper.onTapDown = game.onTapDown;
tapper.onTapUp = game.onTapUp;
tapper.onTapCancel = game.onTapCancel;
flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(tapper);
flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the GestureRecognizers, use the `PanDetector` and `TapDetector` mixins directly on your game class and override the methods that you need.

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with TapDetector, PanDetector {

  MyGame();

  @override
  void onTap() {}

  @override
  void onTapCancel() {}

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onPanDown(DragDownDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {}

  @override
  void onPanCancel() {}
}
```